# Writing (string * int) [] to text file in F#

Tags: f#

I am quite new to F# and this is my first post, so I hope I can provide an adequate description of my problem.
Like the title says I need to write my `(string * int) []` function to a text file. I know of `System.IO.File.WriteAllText (string, string)`, but is there a way for me to write to a text file without converting to a `string` first?
Right now I have a sort of word count, which is sorted with the counted word, and number of times the word occurs. Like so:

```
[|("and", 130); ("he", 128); ("that", 103); ("was", 80); ...|]
```

The file directory of the text file can just be the location of the `.fsx` file from my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need to convert your array somehow. This is usually a good thing, since it forces you to control the format of your file. Of course you could use some sort of serializer, but that's probably a bit much for such a simple task.

I would probably do something like this:

```
open System.IO
let words = [|("and", 130); ("he", 128); ("that", 103); ("was", 80) |]
let lines = words |> Array.map (fun (w, c) -> sprintf "%s;%i" w c)
File.WriteAllLines(__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ + @"\file.csv", lines)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!